# Specify minimum macOS version for Swift Package Manager with Swift 5

Tags: swift, macos, swift-package-manager

In order to have some code compile with SwiftPM, without adding `#if available`, I'm building the project with the following parameters:

`swift build -Xswiftc "-target" -Xswiftc "x86_64-apple-macosx10.11"`

Swift Package Manager also works with Xcode `.xcconfig` files, but only when generating an Xcode project.

Is there an easy way in Swift 5 to specify the minimum version of macOS when building from the command line with `swift build`?

Compiler error example:

```
error: 'archivedData(withRootObject:)' is only available on OS X 10.11 or newer
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: value)
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
let package = Package(
    name: "NAME",
    platforms: [
        .macOS(.v10_11)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(name: "NAME", targets: ["NAME"]),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "NAME"),
    ]
)
```

One way to do this is with [Deployment Settings](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0236-package-manager-platform-deployment-settings.md) in SPM.

Answer (score 1):

Alex 's answer is useful

But when i try to run an old project, still error.
The file header needs to be modified to

```
// swift-tools-version:5.0
```

'platforms' is affective after 5.0